# How to append TinyMCE editor in TinyMCE editor's popup

Tags: plugins, tinymce, plugin-tinymce

I'm trying to make a tinyMCE plugin for wordpress. Here is modal window config:

```
editor.windowManager.open(
    {
        title: 'Title',
        body: [
            {
                type: 'textbox',
                name: 'content',
                label: 'Text',
                value: content,
                multiline: true,
                minWidth: 300,
                minHeight: 100
            }
        ]
    }
);
```

How to make this textbox an editor?